# Error while loading XmlDocument - IOException: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: c#, winforms, xmldocument

I have a network resource , an XML file that I have full access to. In fact I can open that file in notepad and change the contents as well.

But when I access that XML file via XmlDocument.Load() statement, by running an exe under my default windows credentials, it fails with below error.

```
System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
```

I dont know what could be wrong here. All other folks in my same level of authorization can run the exe fine.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582988/can-you-explain-why-directoryinfo-getfiles-produces-this-ioexception

Comment: The user account that the program is running under doesn't have access to the remote server. Have you checked it?

Comment: It has. That is how he could open the same file via Notepad. Isnt it?